# Perspective Switching Pane Gone in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, crash, perspectives

The little Perspective Switching Pane is gone from the upper right hand corner of my Eclipse Window after an Eclipse crash.  I downloaded the newest version and tried opening that (with my same workspace), but the buttons are still gone.

Here is a screenshot:

[image: Full Window]

And zoomed in:

[image: Zoomed in]

Any ideas?

I can still switch perspectives by selecting Window->Open Perspective

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not just the perspective switcher that's missing, it looks to me; there's no tool bars, ether.

You might check Window..Preferences..General..Appearance, and fiddle around with the Perspective Switcher control, see if that makes a difference.

You could also use Window..Customize Perspective and see if anything looks interesting there.

Comment: It was the toolbar.  Window -> Show Toolbar.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try Window > Reset Perspective...

Comment: Close...In the java perspective it changed things around a bit, but didn't add the Perspective Selector back but in the debug Perspective it didn't seem to affect anything.  Thanks for the idea though!

Answer (score 0):

Related. I had my switching pane disabled (I think I moved it by mistake and I could not see it anywhere) although the tool bar was there. The only way I could get it back was to disable themes on Windows -> Preference -> General -> Appearance -> Enable theming.

Answer (score 0):

Using 2022-06 (4.24.0), mine also disappeared.

I was only able to get the buttons back by

- right-clicking and "unlock the toolbar"
- Window->perspective->open perspective->other

After opening each of my favorite perspectives, the buttons "stuck to the bar" then I locked it again when I was done.

Answer (score -1):

Another possibility is to delete the `workbench.xml` from `[workspace]\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.ui.workbench`, which forces the platform to reset the workbench-layout.

Comment: Thanks, but didn't do the trick.  Tried shutting eclipse down, removing the directory, then restarting Eclipse.  Thanks for the idea though!