# Eclipse Neon does not start after trying to fix missing toolbar

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, eclipse-neon

Eclipse Neon does not start after applying the following fix [Eclipse Juno Perspective tool bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17608434/eclipse-juno-perspective-tool-bar/21707508#21707508) for missing toolbar.

I have tried to run:
1) ./eclipse -clean
2) Edit the eclipse.ini with answer here [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36859485)

When I start from command line (1) above after applying 2) above) I get following output in terminal:

```
    :~/eclipse/java-neon/eclipse$ ./eclipse -clean -cleanPersistedState
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: The org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration bundle was activated before the state location was initialized.  Will retry after the state location is initialized.

(Eclipse:13790): GLib-CRITICAL **: 06:24:21.951: g_base64_encode_step: assertion 'in != NULL' failed
....
(Eclipse:13790): GLib-CRITICAL **: 06:24:24.833: g_base64_encode_step: assertion 'in != NULL' failed
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: Logback config file: /home/kilometrics/investments/my_trading/code/.metadata/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration/logback.1.7.0.20160603-1933.xml
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: SLF4J logger factory is not an instance of LoggerContext: org.slf4j.helpers.NOPLoggerFactory

(Eclipse:13790): GLib-CRITICAL **: 06:24:35.585: g_base64_encode_step: assertion 'in != NULL' failed
....
```

And then it crashes without any output...

Answer (score 0):

Though am late, but have you tried this command:

```
export SWT_GTK3=0
```

and then launch eclipse,

```
./eclipse
```

Comment: Thanks. I did. Unfortunately nothing worked and needed to just install new version of Eclipse and rebuild workspace etc.